# How to play a downloaded video file in capacitor ionic by getting the file uri path?

Tags: android, vue.js, ionic-framework, html5-video, capacitor

I have created a [github repo](https://github.com/safaldas/capacitor-image) from the blog post of [joshmorony](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-the-capacitor-filesystem-api-to-store-photos/) to get the camera or gallery image and display it in the page. The camera image displaying works in ios, but **NOT in ANDROID** .

This project also demo another issue https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/2171 .
The project is using "@quasar/app": "^1.0.0"

Answer (score 2):

The problem I see in the sample app is quasar is adding `EnableHttpsSelfSigned.enable(findViewById(R.id.webview));`, which declares a new `WebViewClient`. That prevents Capacitor's `WebViewClient` from working, and the `WebViewClient` is needed to inject Capacitor's javascript and make plugins work.

In your sample app, if I remove that line, then the camera plugin works
https://github.com/safaldas/capacitor-image/blob/master/src-capacitor/android/app/src/main/java/org/cordova/quasar/app/MainActivity.java#L21

I’ve reported it in their repo https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/5823

Should be fixed if you update quasar/app to latest as long as you don’t use https on the dev server